# PHP - Check if $_SESSION exists for multiple variables if not redirect

Tags: php, session

I have the following PHP code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: register.php'); //redirect to the orginal form
} else {
    $businessOwnerID = $_SESSION['business_owner_id']; //The Business owner ID
    $mobileValidation = $_SESSION['mobile_validation'];
}
```

I am not unserstanding why it isn't redirecting to register.php

I tried destroying all sessions by doing session_destroy(); but it did not work either

Comment: Have you started the session on the first line of your file?

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see if there's anything in it? `isset($_SESSION)` would only return false if the session was never started or used previously.

Comment: Please provide all code above that snippet. Even something as simple as a blank line outside of php tags could make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Since you obviously don't really want to just check if there is a session (there pretty much always will be) but if particular session attributes are set, you should be doing it this way:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['business_owner_id'], $_SESSION['mobile_validation']))
{
   session_destroy();
   header('Location: register.php'); //redirect to the original form
} 
...
```

Comment: In my real code I have a whole list of session values (10 or more), I was wondering whether if instead of listing them one by one I'd use `!isset($_SESSION)`

Comment: If you didn't call `session_start()` there is no `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @user2333968, You should always post your real code instead of confusing everyone.

Comment: `session_start()` is already included. @developerwjk if I paste all my code I will create more quesstions than get answers.

Comment: @GolezTrol, Assuming the code he posted is in use, he must have called `session_start()` or it would have redirected.

Comment: @user2333968, In that case make a minimal example, and *run it* and you'll either find the problem isn't what you thought, or if it still persists, you'll have real code you can post in the question without bringing in extra questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SESSION` super global will *always* be set after calling `session_start()`.

Instead, you should check if a particular value is set:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['business_owner_id'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: register.php'); //redirect to the orginal form
} else {
    $businessOwnerID = $_SESSION['business_owner_id']; //The Business owner ID
    $mobileValidation = $_SESSION['mobile_validation'];
}
```